# Add class on scroll not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm in essence attempting to extract (in the roughest manner possible) the header from [this website](http://americavotes.org/). What they do is they add an additional class when the user scrolls at a position > 0. I assumed that this would be straight-forward, but java always has a way of causing me problems. I came up with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    height: 5000px;
  }
  #scroll {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white
  }
  .test {
    background-color: red;
    color: pink;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction();
  };

  function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "test";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "";
    }
  }
</script>

<body>

  <div class="box" id="scroll">THIS ISNT WORKING</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The class applies when I scroll down, but not when I scroll back up. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag!

Comment: ... JavaScript is correct. BUT JavaScript IS NOT Java !!! (but hey no problem, just remember ;) )

Comment: You can use classList add/remove .Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the secret, in this line:

```
document.getElementById("scroll").className = "";
```

you don't set it back to it's old class `box` so it just has no class when scrolling back top. Change it like this:

```
  function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "test";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "box";
    }
  }
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    height: 5000px;
  }
  #scroll {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white
  }
  .test {
    background-color: red;
    color: pink;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction();
  };

  function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "test";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("scroll").className = "box";
    }
  }
</script>

<body>

  <div class="box" id="scroll">THIS ISNT WORKING</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was perfect! I really need to get better at java, ahah.

Comment: @Hanna JavaScript, don't kill me^^

Comment: -oh my god forgive me-

Answer (score 0):

Rather than completely changing the `className` you can use `classList add/remove` to add or remove class.

Here is a situation.

Suppose you need some common css properties in both the condition and I hope you wont like to add these properties in both the css class. That will cause a redundancy.

Let us take this css class

```
.box {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .test {
    background-color: red;
    color: pink;
```

}

If you completely remove the `box` it will remove the `text-align` & `font-size` property also,which you may want to remain same.

Here is a code and [JSFIDDLE WITH EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/29kroety/1/)

HTML

```
// Note there is an empty space beside box ,otherwise it will con-cat with 
//class add through class list and resultant will be boxtest

<div class="box " id="scroll">THIS ISNT WORKING</div>
```

JS

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    myFunction();
  };
function myFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
      document.getElementById("scroll").classList.add('test');
    } else {
      document.getElementById("scroll").classList.remove('test');
    }
  }
```

CSS

```
body {
    height: 5000px;
  }
  #scroll {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .test {
    background-color: red;
    color: pink;
  }
```